# Making a Matplotlib table interactive using PyQt

Tags: matplotlib, user-interface, button, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a project which is to make a chemistry periodic **table using matplotlib** and making it **user-interactive using PyQt**. The interactivity would be: when a cell/element is clicked on, more information about the element should be displayed, e.g. element full name, group, type, number of valence, ... (in a new window?). I already made the matplotlib periodic table which can be stored in PeriodicTablev1.plt.figure(), but I am struggling to make the PyQt environment which includes the periodic table. I am new to pyqt, so I find this quite hard. These are what I think could be options:

- Rewrite the table within the pyqt environment and go from there
- Import the table and "copy-paste it" into the pyqt environment and indicate clickable locations

Let me know which solutions are best

This is the code I have now, the matplotlib periodic table was made using matplotlib.table.Cell (PeriodicTablev1.py) (I don't think I have to include that here) and imported in into the pyqt code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import PeriodicTablev1
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)  # Adjust the window size as needed
    window.setWindowTitle("Periodic table")

    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    # Add the Matplotlib table to the layout
    table_figure = PeriodicTablev1.plt.figure()
    table_canvas = FigureCanvas(table_figure)
    layout.addWidget(table_canvas)

    # Add the button to the layout
    label = QLabel("Table blablblabala")
    button = QPushButton("Clickable cell")
    button.clicked.connect(on_clicked)
    layout.addWidget(label)
    layout.addWidget(button)

    window.setLayout(layout)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


def on_clicked():
    message = QMessageBox()
    message.setText("Element info")
    message.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code only displays the original table in 1 window and the pyqt application in another separate one. How can I include the table itself in the pyqt application and make it interactive as described above? I know this is the very basics of pyqt, but if anyone could enlighten me on how I can approach this would be greatly appreciated :)

PS: Here is the table (PeriodicTablev1) that I want to make interactive:

[image: PeriodictTablev1.plt.figure()]

Comment: I don't know how much effort you put into creating such a table in matplotlib, but that wouldn't be my first choice, since that's not the main purpose of that library. Such a table could be achieved easily in Qt by using a QTableWidget or through the Graphics View framework, and both of them would then make such interaction quite simple (for QTableWidget it would be just a matter of connecting the `itemClicked` signal).